# Clicked element changes the style of other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following html with three identical ellipses. The file *style.css* defines the styles `unselected-key` and `selected-key`.  Using pure JavaScript/CSS I want to achieve that when an ellipse is clicked its style changes from `unselected-key` to `selected-key` and every other ellipse gets the style `unselected-key`. The solution should adapt easily to the case of a large number of ellipses in the svg image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Experiment</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Major keys</h1>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="g-14" class="unselected-key">
       <ellipse cx="346.176" cy="15.569" rx="22.2" ry="22.2" />
       <text x="346.176" y="15.569">1</text>
    </g>
    <g id="g-15" class="unselected-key">
       <ellipse cx="451.176" cy="43.704" rx="22.2" ry="22.2" />
       <text x="451.176" y="43.704">2</text>
    </g>
    <g id="g-16" class="unselected-key">
       <ellipse cx="528.041" cy="120.569" rx="22.2" ry="22.2" />
       <text x="528.041" y="120.569">3</text>
    </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what you've tried so far ? this is not a code service site

Comment: It is expected that you have made an attempt to come up with a solution. What did you find when researching this issue?

Comment: ```const container = document.querySelector('#group-of-keys');
const unselected_key_ellipse = document.querySelectorAll(".unselected-key ellipse");
container.addEventListener('click', event => {
    unselected_key_ellipse.forEach(el => {
        if (el.classList.contains('selected-key')){
            el.classList.remove('selected-key');
        }
        el.classList.add('unselected-key');
    });
    if (event.target.classList.contains('unselected-key')) {
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected-key');
    }
    event.target.classList.add('selected-key');
});```

Comment: I added a <g id="container"> tag all around the three groups containing the ellipses

Answer (score 0):

Without any joke: As you called this "Experiment" I did an experiment myself. I put your HTML in VSCode and asked the Github Copilot to do the following:

> // add a listener to the svg ellipses so when an ellipse is clicked, the class of the ellipse is changed to selected-key and all
> other ellipses are changed to unselected-key. If the ellipse is
> already selected, the class is not changed to unselected-key.

It did spit out this:

```
 var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
 svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.tagName === 'ellipse') {
     var selectedKey = e.target.parentNode;
     var unselectedKeys = document.querySelectorAll('g:not(#' + selectedKey.id + ')');
     for (var i = 0; i < unselectedKeys.length; i++) {
       unselectedKeys[i].classList.remove('selected-key');
       unselectedKeys[i].classList.add('unselected-key');
     }
     selectedKey.classList.remove('unselected-key');
     selectedKey.classList.add('selected-key');
   }
 });
```

What should I say? For me it works. I'm probably roasted for this, but I found it funny enough to still post it.

Comment: Funny thing is: Copilot even write most of the comment describing what I want itself. And it was mostly right.